# How to disable replacing the app root div with the component HTML while using templates

Tags: vuejs2

So basically, when using components - the app root passed to the Vue instance gets replaced by whatever HTML is in the component. Is there a way to disable this and just nest the stuff Vue renders inside the app root instead?

for example - if index.html has a wrapper of

```
<div id="myVueApp"></div>
```

and I set el: "#myVueApp" on the Vue instance, the whole node will get removed and replaced by whatever I have in my template resulting in

```
<div id="myComponent">...</div>
```

Is there a way to make it into

```
<div id="myVueApp">
    <div id="myComponent">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work. From what I understand, you want to have multiple parts of your Vue app to be splitted up in the rendered HTML output as well, more specifically into multiple divs.

I think this should work if you use multiple Vue instances. 
Set up a structure in your HTML file and give them appropriate id's.
Then, create the Vue instances you want and assign each of them to their specific `div` using `el`.

However, I can't tell you if this is a good idea and follows the best practice..

Hope this helps!

Comment: The thing is - this is for an SDK I'm working on. So i have no idea which placeholder the end-users will use. I have a init() method which (among other things) takes the DOM placeholder and renders everything in it.

At this point - vue removes that div and replaces it with mine. So if the end user needs to destroy the instance, or at any point re-render it again (for whatever reason) - the initial div does not exist any more.

Comment: Okay I see.. if your `init()` is getting all the id's, have you tried to setup your Vue instances using these placeholder id's in the `el` option? As long as you have a fixed number of `divs` your users will be able to use, this could work. If it is up to the user how many elements they create, then this won't work either..

Comment: I have multiple items that the user can draw but every one of them will be put in a single placeholder. So each instance gets drawn only once. I could use the placeholder name and bind it to the initial wrapper but i would have to check if it's a class or an ID reference - or just limit users to use IDs only. I found the "replace" property of vue (does exactly what i need) but that looks deprecated and it's set to "true" by default now :(